# why does the image size differ between when i retrieve canvas image with jpg and jpeg?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var dataURL = canvasImg.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

The above line give dataURL of length ~20KB.

```
var dataURL = canvasImg.toDataURL("image/jpg");
```

But the above line gives dataURL of length ~100KB.

But i have read that there is no difference between jpg and jpeg.

Can some one please explain why does this happen?

Comment: Did you mean to differentiate between jpg and jpeg in your question?

Comment: image/jpg means nothing, so it defaults.

Comment: @dandavis: Yes, [defaults to PNG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement), to be specific.

Comment: @voithos: oops, i got cut-off. that's what i was getting at, thanks for  clarifying...

Comment: @dandavis: Perhaps post your comment as an answer? Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xD4rU/1/) that shows this happening.

Comment: @voithos:Thanks a lot. I was not knowing this till now.